# time formatting in python combined with sys module

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine sys module and time module in python?
I want to write a program that check if the sys argument that the user has put in is in the right time format e.g. "%H:%M"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass timestamp as a command line argument in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343230/how-to-pass-timestamp-as-a-command-line-argument-in-python)

Comment: Semi-duplicates: [How to validate a specific Date and Time format using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18539266/4518341) and [What's the best way to parse command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20063/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Read about argparse, it's a nice library for parsing arguments in python,
You can find it in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

One approach for handling that question would be to use `type` argument while adding it to parser, the type can be any function that will validate your format. e.g -

```
def validate(arg):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(arg, "%H:%M")
    except ValueError:
        msg = f"Invalid date fmt {arg}"
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
```

Now just assign above function as type while adding argument by `parser.add_argument`.